# Fire damper required/advised in 2 family brownstone?

Tags: hvac, code-compliance, ducts, fire-hazard

**TL;DR** Does New York building code require fire dampers for partial renovation of four storey brownstone with two family CO?

I live in a two family New York brownstone which is undergoing a partial renovation. The upper unit comprising the top three floors was renovated while the ground level unit was left as is. I am working with a professional architect and mechanical engineer, but have received inconsistent and confusing guidance from the engineer, most recently on fire dampers.

Fire dampers with access panels were specified in the original drawings. The contractor installed the dampers, but didn’t install the access panels. Now we can’t pass the inspection because the inspector needs to see the dampers. This has opened a discussion about whether fire dampers are necessary in our building, with the contractor insisting they weren’t needed in the first place. The mechanical eng initially said that dampers were “not required by code, but advised” but now says that they are required since we don’t have subducts.

Do we need these fire dampers, and if so why? As I understand it the dampers are to stop fire spreading through the kitchen ventilation duct, which runs from the lower unit stove hood to a roof ceiling fan, with a junction that incorporates the duct from the upper unit stove hood. But the floors are just wooden joists and there are open stairwells between the floors in the upper triplex so it’s not clear to me how this would prevent fire spreading.

Bonus question - should the mech Eng have specified subducts instead of fire dampers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NYC code is a bit quiet on this topic

NYC Code section MC505 is silent on the topic of common domestic kitchen exhausts that serve multiple dwelling units, so one would normally assume that MC607.5's requirements would apply here.  *However*, NYCMC 607.5 requires that fire dampers be applied within their listing, and the conditions (warm to hot exhaust temperatures, grease impingement) in a kitchen exhaust would likely fall outside the listing and labeling of a UL 555 fire damper (although I can't find anything definitive in the UL Guide Info saying this).

### ...but the current model codes weigh in, and their answer is "you can't do that!"

However, the ICC Mechanical Code committee spoke firmly on this topic when they wrote newer editions of the IMC, as section 505.5 in the 2021 IMC prohibits any damper other than the backdraft damper specified in IMC 505.3 from being installed in a common domestic kitchen exhaust system, and invokes an exception (607.5.5 Exception 2) that removes the requirement for fire dampers at shaft penetrations.

So, I'd say that that settles it: fire dampers in domestic kitchen exhaust ducts are a Bad Idea, and likely indeed a violation of the fire damper's listing, even if your jurisdiction has not adopted a new enough IMC to explicitly prohibit such an application.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Would you be able to expand some more on why they are a Bad Idea i.e. the spirit of the IMC? Is it because the conditions you describe (warm to hot air with grease) could cause the damper to fail to operate? Or because the damper could accumulate grease and become a hazard in its own right? Or something else?

Comment: @jweob both a and b -- grease accumulation (or chronic excessive temperatures) could cause the damper to malfunction, and the damper also represents another point where grease could accumulate